# Default values for model fields in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple Action in my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int itemId)
    {
        return View(new EditModel() { ItemId = itemId + 1 });
    }

    public class EditModel
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem comes in the View, when I try to display everything.

```
Model.ItemId: @Model.ItemId
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Since action parameter and property on EditModel have the same name (`itemId`) I get the following:

[image]

Is this a correct behaviour? How can I change default value displayed inside a form in that case?

Comment: I know the solution :) This just hadn't seem to be a correct behavior to me - because it really can confuse

Comment: Yes it is confusing. Yesterday I spent half of a day trying to resolve simmilar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be somehow confusing for the first look, but yes, this is default(correct) behavior. [Controller.ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate.aspx) is the privileged supplier for the values when you use `EditorFor` or similar editor helpers, over the model itself. But there's trickier point in your situation.

ModelState is populated with action parameters and values that take part in model binding.  When you call that action, `ModelState` is populated with `"ItemId" = action parameter(itemId) value`. Later, `EditorFor` sees that is should draw editor for `ItemId`. As ModelState has already got `ItemId`, it does not look at model value, but extracts it from `ModelState["ItemId"]`. Tricky source of your error is that action parameter name matches the model property name and modelState prefers that over model value. The best solution (clean one) would be to just rename action parameter, so that it does not match the model property name.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int initialItemId)
        {
            return View(new EditModel() { itemId = initialItemId + 1 });
        }
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it is so. The easiest solution is to rename, yes (in my real task there's even no need to rename, because that behavior suits me :)), it would be just good if VS or something notified about that, because I can easily imagine hours of debugging, when this "trick" will be used unintendedly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
Model.ItemId: @Model.ItemId
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
```

Or hide ItemId for edit with metadata